# NULL Value inserted in Database (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I Am trying to insert data in DB,But somehow **NULL** is inserted in DB

**Here Is My Controller**

```
foreach($this->input->post('resume_id') as $key =>$value ){

                $ResumeInsert[$key]['resume_keyid'] = $Resume['resume_id'][$key];
                $ResumeInsert[$key]['employer_name'] = $Resume['employer_name'][$key];
                $ResumeInsert[$key]['start_Date'] = $Resume['start_Date'][$key];
                $ResumeInsert[$key]['end_date'] = $Resume['end_date'][$key];
                $ResumeInsert[$key]['type_id'] = $Resume['type_id'][$key];
                $ResumeInsert[$key]['position'] = $Resume['position'][$key];
                $ResumeInsert[$key]['responsibility'] = $Resume['responsibility'][$key];
                $ResumeInsert[$key]['Skills'] = $Resume['Skills'][$key];

                if(isset($Resume['id'][$key]) ){
                    $Key_Resume__ExistIDs[]=$Resume['id'][$key];
                    $ResumeUpdate[$key]=$ResumeInsert[$key];
                    $ResumeUpdate[$key]['resume_id']=$Resume['id'][$key];
                    unset($ResumeInsert[$key]);
                }
                 else{

                     $ResumeInsert[$key]['resume_id'] = $GetLastID;
                     print_r ($ResumeInsert[$key]);exit;
                     $GetLastID++;
                } 
            }
            $idsToDelete='';
            if(empty($ResumeInsert) &&  empty($ResumeUpdate)){

                $idsToDelete=array_diff($Key_Resume_IDs,$Key_Resume__ExistIDs);
            }
            $status=$this->Resume_model->ProcessData($idsToDelete,$ResumeUpdate,$user_id,$ResumeInsert,$imgInsert,$imgUpdate);

            redirect('Resume','refresh');
```

**Here Is My Code Of Model**

```
function ProcessData($idsToDelete,$tbl_resumeUpdate,$user_id,$tbl_resumeInsert,$imgInsert,$imgUpdate){
    $this->db->trans_start();
    if(!empty($idsToDelete)){
        $this->delete_tbl_resume($idsToDelete);
    }
    if(!empty($tbl_resumeUpdate)){
        //echo "up";exit;
        $this->update_tbl_resume($tbl_resumeUpdate);
    }
    if(!empty($tbl_resumeInsert)){
        //echo "int";exit;
        $this->insert_tbl_resume($user_id,$tbl_resumeInsert);
    }
    if(!empty($imgInsert)){
        $this->insert_tbl_file_paths($imgInsert);
    }
    if(!empty($imgUpdate)){
        $this->update_tbl_file_paths($imgUpdate);
    }
    return $this->db->trans_complete();
}
```

**This is Insert Query**

```
function insert_tbl_resume($id,$arrtbl_resume){
    $this->db->insert_batch('tbl_resume', $arrtbl_resume); 

}
```

In Above Code,Null Value inserted In DB.
when i Print above query,it displays blank

Any Help Please?

Comment: Within the function`insert_tbl_resume` did you check the value of `$arrtbl_resume` ?

Comment: yup..it dispay  , **Array ( [0] => Array ( [resume_keyid] => [employer_name] => [start_Date] => [end_date] => [type_id] => [position] => [responsibility] => [Skills] => [resume_id] => 52 ) ) **

Comment: check the value of `$Resume` array within the for loop `foreach($this->input->post('resume_id') as $key =>$value ){`. Also make sure that `for` loop is executing before calling the insert query function.

Comment: @SankarV :- it blanks

Comment: so when you send blank array to the insert function, what do you expect to get inserted in the database?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `form_validation` library. I'm giving you an example, you can edit and use it.

In autoload.php, edit `$autoload['libraries'] = array();` line to:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('form_validation');
```

Then, use `form_validation` in your controller file. For example:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('resume_keyid', 'Resume ID', 'required');

if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) 
{
   $this->index() // if there is an error, user will redirect to this function
}

else 
{
  $this->Resume_model->ProcessData();
}
```

Also please use `$this->input->post('resume_keyid', TRUE);` structure in your model. "TRUE" means "open XSS filter". Because in CI 3, it comes off as default. If you don't want it, just remove. If you use CI 2, you don't need to add "TRUE".

A few suggestions:

1 - Don't use camelization when you name functions. For example; use `process_data()` instead of `processData()`

2 - Check [CI Form Validation Document](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html) for all details (E.g. all references)

3 - I think you can use `$this->db->insert();`, just create an array and `POST` it. If you make it, you'll understand what's wrong.